# Query returning 0 instead of data

Tags: mysql, database, lumen

I am working in Lumen.
I am trying to fetch data from database.

This is the the query:

```
$subcategories = SubCategory::all();
return $subcategories;
```

**Output**

> [{
>           "coid": 0,
>           "image": null,
>           "name": "PULSES",
>           "subcatid": "C001"
>       }]

But, **coid** should be **CI001**

When I search data using coid, like

```
$sub = SubCategory::where('coid', 'C001')->first();
```

**OUTPUT**

> [{
>           "coid": 0,
>           "image": null,
>           "name": "PULSES",
>           "subcatid": "C001"
>       }]

**Structure of coid**

```
$table->string('coid')->primary();
```

Varchar(119)

why is this happening and how to fix this?

Comment: if coid is `primary` then it should not 0.

Comment: Data is correct in database, but recieve 0 when got through query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you set another col to primary in lumen it will **auto increment by default**!
For solve it **use this in your SubCategory model** :

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

**Note** : You can set coid to be primary key in SubCategory model like this:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'coid ';
```

And Then use find method to find it:

```
SubCategory::find('C001);
```